# Why is importing an icon named ImportExport breaking other dependencies?

Tags: babeljs, es6-modules, parceljs, esmodules

I added a Material-UI icon to one of my react components like so:

```
import { ImportExport } from '@material-ui/icons';
```

Thereafter, on my production site (but not my localhost dev server), I started getting an error on pageload whereby my socket-io client library was unable to correctly import something in one of its internal files. It had this:

```
const encodePacket = require("./encodePacket");
```

Which was used like so:

```
encodePacket(packet, false, encodedPacket => {
```

This is where the error arises: `TypeError: encodePacket is not a function.` Inspecting it, I can see that `encodePacket` is indeed not a function. When printed in the console, it shows as `{default: {…}, __esModule: true}`.

On my localhost dev server, this isn't the case. It's a function as expected. Moreover, the import right next to it, for `decodePacket`, is still a function in *both* contexts, locally and in production.

More bizarrely, when I examine the `encodePacket` module in the console, it looks like this:

[image]

Mui is Material-UI, a UI lib I use in other parts of the application and from which the icon is sourced - obviously it has no connection to a network library's internal packet encoding logic.

By commenting out the `ImportExport` icon and its import, I found that the error goes away.

What on earth though? How could this happen?

I even tried renaming the icon, but that didn't work either~

```
    import { ImportExport as ReverseSortIcon } from '@material-ui/icons';
```

Any suggestions? I'm using Parcel and this is my tsconfig that has worked for 2+ years uneventfully~

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./dist/",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "strict": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "module": "es6",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "target": "es5",
    "allowJs": true,
    "jsx": "react",
    "esModuleInterop": true
  },
  "include": [
    "./src/**/*"
  ]
}
```

*Edit*: I have later discovered that this bug also results from importing an icon named `Lock`, i.e.:
`import { Lock } from '@material-ui/icons';`

Comment: what versions of parcel and those dependencies are you using?

Comment: Do you have a lockfile checked into git?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like an issue of using the `import` syntax where you probably use `require` everywhere else.
Using the `import` syntax turns your file into an ES module instead of a CJS one.

For now I you could try to use the require syntax for the icons:

```js
const { ImportExport } = require('@material-ui/icons');
```

Another idea could be to use the encodePacket ES module with require (just add `.default` at the end):

```js
const encodePacket = require("./encodePacket").default;
```

But as it is internal to socket.io it is not that practical, so I'd rather try to import socket.io as ES module, too:

```js
import { io } from "socket.io-client";
```

Comment: I use `import` throughout the whole application.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your local dev server and the production server have the same versions and dependencies. Try this on both machines:

- check the used npm and nodejs versions (`npm -v`, `node -v`)
- delete `node_modules` and reinstall all packages (clean install sometimes solves problems that look impossible)
- delete the parcel cache and build again

Possible workaround: If all that does not help then you could maybe just deploy the build directory from your dev machine instead of building on the server.